# Использование REGEXP

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Читая книгу, вижу замечание:

> REGEXP() используется только тогда, когда шаблон заранее не известен и создается во время заполнения.

Пожалуйста, приведите наглядный пример.

Comment: Непонятно как-то.

Comment: Приведите контекст. Без контекста — туфта какая-то)

Comment: Стефанова книга ст.78

Comment: У нас нет этой книги.

Comment: Нужно учится формулировать вопросЫ.Книга крутая.С Рутрекер если хотите качайте не помешает.

Comment: Небось имеется ввиду литерал против конструктора...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, они имели в виду различие между `/foo/` и `new RegExp("foo")`. Объект, который они возвращают будет точно такой же, а вот применение у них разное.

Если шаблон известен заранее, на момент написания кода, то мы и сделаем соответствующе. Например:

```
/^\d{2,4}/.test(...)
```

Но если шаблон, на момент написания кода неизвестен, и как-то вычисляется, то единственный вариант — компилировать регулярное выражение из строки:

```
var min = 2,
    max = 4;
new RegExp("^\\d{" + min + "," + max + "}").test(...)
```

Потому что написать как-то в духе `/\d{$min,$max}/` мы не можем, это JavaScript, а не Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Ну скажем так, RegExp используется тогда, когда формат всё же известен, но он не четкий. Например:

есть строка:

```
12345 some text 67890
```

т.е идёт число, потом текст, потом снова число, размер которое занимает число или текст заранее не известен. Может быть

```
1 text 2
```

а может быть

```
28372848734637 iureifkdfv;dfkgjihsd 37433473463
```

Поэтому мы будем использовать RegExp

```
/(\d+)(.*?)(\d+)/
```

или

```
/(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)/
```

или

```
/(\d+)([^\d]+)(\d+)/
```

ну и т.д

Comment: пасиб за комент